# Multi windows error androidmanifest.xml

Tags: java, android, multi-window

I am trying to insert nell'android manifest support for multi windows .. that's what I did:

```
<application
        <uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.X.XX.XXX"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Why do I receive an error? How can i fix it?

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `>` at the first line, after `<application`

Comment: No.. It's meant to be that way.. It is in the `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >` line

Comment: also putting the error persists. the error is here         <uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" />
 ( attribute is missing the android namespace prefix )

Answer (score 2):

You're putting it in the wrong place.. According to the [[MOD] Multiwindow Apps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1985240) It should be inserted right before the ending `application` tag.

In your case you should use the following:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.X.XX.XXX"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
</application>
```

EDIT: I added namespace prefixes as suggested by other answer.

Answer (score 1):

> the error is here  ( attribute is missing the android namespace prefix )

Replace:

```
<uses-library required="false" name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" />
```

with:

```
<uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" />
```

Comment: The Problem is that he is putting it in the wrong place.. He is putting a tag inside attributes of another tag..

Comment: @MiroMarkarian: They are both problems. The `<uses-library>` element will not work without the namespace prefixes, either. That being said, your issue is somewhat more blatant -- I'm surprised that Lint is even getting to the point of complaining about namespace prefixes.